# Foundation's 4 form dropdown style missing on IE8 and below

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation 4 framework for one of my websites, and I noticed that when testing it on Internet Explorer 8 or below the form dropdowns are being displayed as the IE default rendering instead of the Foundation's javascript one.

Does anyone know how can I change the javascript to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: IE8 and lower is officially not supported in Foundation 4. Please, look for more info here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/support.html

Answer (score 0):

Look to use Foundation 3.2.5, which you can find the documentation here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/3.2.5/  This is the highest version of foundation that is supporting IE 8.

Answer (score 0):

Foundation 4 do not support IE8 and lower. Use older version of Foundation, or newer version of IE.